# WPF C# Custom UserControl How To add a Property which accepts an Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I'm trying to design a CustomUserControl which consits of an TextEditor and a PopUp...

So the Popup control should be binded to a list...
I called it BindingList. This Property should accept any types like ObservableCollection, List, Ienumerable for example(Collections)...

```
<my:CustomControl BindingList="{Binding Path=Collection}"


 public IEnumerable<object> BindingList
    {
        get { return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(BindingListProp); }
        set { SetValue(BindingListProp, value); }
    }
```

The BindinglistProp

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingListProp = DependencyProperty.Register(??????
```

I have no clue how it should look like that it can accept a binding.

And how should i deal with the Collection which is passed? when it is of a type which i don`t know

like

```
    class Person
    {
        private string _Name;
        private string _forename;


        public string Name
        {
            get { return _Name; }
            set
            {
                _Name = value;
            }
        }

        public string Forename
        {
            get { return _forename; }
            set
            {
                _forename = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any hints, tutorials or code snippets.

sincerely
Mark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public IObservable<object> BindingList
{
  get { return (IObservable<object>)base.GetValue(BindingListProperty); }
  set { base.SetValue(BindingListProperty, value); }
}

public static DependencyProperty BindingListProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(
  "BindingList",
  typeof(IObservable<object>),
  typeof(CustomControl),
  new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

Comment: And maybe IObservable instead of IEnumerable?

Comment: How can I access, what I have binded in the CustomControl ? When i'm binding it with an ObservableCollection the property remains null.  I'm sorry for all the questions...

Answer (score 1):

Look to the [CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview.aspx) to work with any collection in common way.